# it possible to run selenium test in multiple tabs in parallel

Tags: python, selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver

i have simple code i want it to run in same time on multiple tabs on the same browser
i am already try to do it by using threads but the problem is the automation run only on focused tab

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url = 'http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryregister.php?osCsid=f72a65d645d1646e69f1cc8f0bfe5175'


def test_case(i):

    driver.execute_script("window.open()")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_name('firstName').send_keys('test test')
    driver.find_element_by_name('lastName').send_keys('test test')
    driver.find_element_by_name('phone').send_keys('test test')
    driver.find_element_by_name('userName').send_keys('test_test@gmail.com')
    driver.find_element_by_name('address1').send_keys('test test test test')
    driver.find_element_by_name('city').send_keys('test test')
    driver.find_element_by_name('postalCode').send_keys('test test')
    driver.find_element_by_name('register').click()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_case, args=[1])
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_case, args=[2])
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_case, args=[3])

p1.start()
sleep(3)
p2.start()
sleep(6)
p3.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
```

Comment: why you are not using multiple instances of webdriver rather than multiple tabs.It would be easy to do parallel processing with  multiple browser instance.

Comment: i want to use one browser because in my test case i need to do login in first for that i want to login in just one time

Comment: you can only do this using 1 thread per driver.  I believe there is a technique for attaching a new driver to an existing browser session... (you use the same session id, but it's very quirky and I think causes multiple browser sessions to open that you never use...)

Comment: the reason is that the driver has a specific window/tab handle.  It cannot have multiple handles in different threads.  (Though I bet that is possible!  Maybe it's planned for future webdriver releases?  They already have put in threading of sorts for "ticks", for automating tasks like two fingers on a screen...) https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#ticks